# when using open xml my file gets corrupt

Tags: c#, xml

EDIT:
the problem is now solved, it was that there is xml code which is named 'name' which i was accidentally changing. the solution was to have a obscure name in the docx file

---

I am creating a program that modify a word document using open xml but every time the program runs the file gets corrupt and i don't know why or if there is any  way around it?

i have had a look and one thing i saw was too make sure i had closed the connection but i tried that but i'm not sure if the connection is still opened

edit:

the output file says it corrupt but when the recovery in ms word run the files is as it should be

from the images/code 
the the original file is copied to temp.docx and has "name" in the file

i require the program to replace "name" with another word.

the program is semi working as it changes the value of the document however it is corrupting the document.

link to photos: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B130JvN0ZPPRODJpZWZENTNUX0E

CODE

```
private void gen_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\invoices\temp.docx"))
        {
            // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to 
            // handle the case of the file already being 
            // opened by another process. 
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\invoices\temp.docx");
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
        File.Copy(@"C:\invoices\template.docx", @"C:\invoices\temp.docx");
        SearchAndReplace("name", "asdsadsadasdasdas");
    }

   public static void SearchAndReplace(string wordtoreplace, string replace)

    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\invoices\temp.docx", true))
        {
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Regex regexText = new Regex(wordtoreplace);
            docText = docText.Replace(wordtoreplace, replace);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);

            }
            wordDoc.Close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: `the file gets corrupt` - HOW? You seem to be doing seldom more then find & replace, are you sure you are not corrupting it yourself by replacing a bad value? What is your input, what is your desired output, what is your actual output? Voting to close for lack of details given.

Comment: Could you provide more details about file you are using, its showing .docx file, instead you may need to use xml file?

Comment: Hi i have edit my post with a link to my document photos. hopefully it provides a better picture of what my problem is.

Comment: @MattClark Hi what do you mean by 'bad value' and what is a example of one as the value i am replacing 'name' with is 'asdsadsadasdasdas'.

Comment: @RaghuAriga Hi it should work with .docx as the images it just put up does work but the file gets corrupted in the process. But i'm not 100% sure  :)

Comment: The real shame here is that this code is basically from the Microsoft docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx. I don't know why Microsoft would think this code is generally acceptable if you can ruin the XML directly.

Comment: @KSib why is it a shame???

Comment: @R1CH101your code isn't a shame, but the fact that microsoft provided code to change text in a document, while also letting you ruin the XML schema at the same time. There should be either a better library they offer for simply setting the text or the property or the example should denote that you could corrupt the document this way.

Comment: @KSib I knew (well actually hoped) it won't my code, but i see what you mean. I agree Microsoft should put something in place to stop you using certain words which XML also uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the document stream you are opening is an XML document.  It contains much more than the words that are typed in your document.  There are XML attributes named "name" that are being replaced by your code which make the document no longer validate against the schema.

You can continue doing a plain text replace if you use more unique terms.  For example, if your search term is "asdf", then it would be pretty safe to replace because that value won't appear in the XML schema.

To do this correctly, you need to parse the XML document.  The XML elements that contain the actual text are named "w:t".  If you loop through all of the "w:t" XML elements, you can do your plain text replace on their "InnerText" values.  This will guarantee that your XML will remain valid.

Note that you will still have problems if you try to parse the XML directly...  If you type your token text ("name" in this case), then apply some kind of format (like bold) to the middle of the word, you will no longer be able to find "name" in a single "w:t" element.  By applying the format, the text "name" will be broken up into more than one "w:t" elements.  To get this to work in my project, I applied an intermediate step that merged the "w:t" elements before I searched for the tokens.  The trick here is knowing when the elements can't be merged due to formatting differences.

Comment: Thank you i changes the name of the text in the file to 'name123456789asd' and it worked. :)

Comment: *changed  (grammar mistakes)